# Trying to add formula to a column in Excel output using C# Windows application. But getting #NAME? error

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am using Windows app to export data into the Excel. Assigned the below formula in lastcolumn

```
=IFNA(IF(VLOOKUP(CONCAT(S2,T2),'data table'!$C:$C,1,0)=CONCAT(S2,T2),"Yes"),"No")
```

. The excel is already having 'data table' sheet. I got the output with formula in the Excel column but its showing #NAME? error. when i double click on the cell then exit from the cell, value of the formula is coming. Not sure why i am not getting the value without double clicking on the cell manually.

Could someone please help me to get the value of the formula when i export from application. 
Thanks in Advance!!

Comment: I have assigned formulas to the excel cell as below using c# code: lrow = Ws.LastRowUsed.RowNumber()

                    For n = 1 To lrow - 1
                        StrFormula = "=IFNA(IF(VLOOKUP(CONCAT(S" & currentRow & ",T" & currentRow & "),'datatable'!$C:$C,1,0)=CONCAT(S" & currentRow & ",T" & currentRow & "),""Yes""),""No"")"
                        Ws.Cells("AK" & currentRow).FormulaA1 = StrFormula
                        currentRow = currentRow + 1
                    Next

Comment: I think it may need `CONCATENATE`, why not try `match` instead?  Vlookups purpose is to return the adjacent columns, match is a better method for one column

Comment: i am doing VLOOKUP with another sheet named 'data table'.

Comment: Yes, and you can still use `match` `countif` etc, seems inefficient yo use vlookup.  Look at the match function, see what i mean

Comment: Also, i dont believe that your ISNA is correct, this needs to surround the lookup, not it's equality check.  Something like `if(isna(vlookup(value,data,column)),"Yes","No")`

Comment: I used Concatenate instead of CONCAT as you suggested, then checked Error in Formulas. While checking the calculation steps for the error, getting #NAME? for IFNA condition

Comment: Sorry, i read as ISNA, You dont need to do the equality check, just `=IFNA(vlookup,value if na)` so i'd use `ISNA` as a wrapper around the vlookup without the equality as described `if(isna(vlookup(value,data,column)),"No","Yes")`

Comment: IFNA was added relatively recently, it is unknow to e.g. Excel 2013.

Comment: I am using Excel 2016 and getting #NAME? error only when the output is generated. If i open the output file and double click on the cell then getting value of the formula

Comment: I have tried the below formula, but its not working. Excel is opening without the formula column. "=IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(CONCATENATE(S" & currentRow & ",T" & currentRow & "),'datatable'!$C:$C;1;0)),""No"",""Yes"")"

Comment: Sorry.. it was my mistake in the above formula...  if(isna(vlookup(value,data,column)),"No","Yes") this concept is worked for me... Thank you Nathan_Sav!!!

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
=IFNA(IF(VLOOKUP(CONCATENATE(C2;D2);'data table'!A:A;1;0)=CONCATENATE(C2;D2);"Yes");"No")
```

I have been using Excel 2013 and worked correctly.

Comment: i have tried with ; instead of , as you suggested its throwing error while opening the output excel